# Is there a way to scale unity's render view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, unityscript

I'm looking to make a game that looks similar to old PS1 games with their rough edges for the rendered models. I'm just starting with Unity, coming from Game Maker, and in Game Maker you could set the width and height of the game's viewport and then upscale it, doubling each pixel's scale, essentially incrementing the render view to achieve a "scaled look". I was wondering if there was a way to do this with Unity.
If anyone has any information on this, that'd be great!

Comment: Do you have a picture to show as an example?

Comment: Do you mean "pixelated" look, may be? As in, first render to 320x480 and then upscale it to 640x960?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a script to do it for me. After much searching, I found [this](http://davidgrenzowski.tumblr.com/post/79103002541/more) snippet to that accomplishes what I'm looking for.